# How to access private google spread sheet using node js?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets

I am using [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) but it only access the published public spread sheet. Is there any way to access private spread sheet ?

If i used unpublished spread sheet it shows

> Error: HTTP error 403: Forbidden

[image]

Is there any way to access private google spread sheet using javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a private spreadsheet you need to authorize your request.

In order to do that you'll need to register your application with google and go through the OAuth2 flow.

You can find more information about that here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

And a nodejs library that will help you do this here: https://github.com/samcday/node-google-spreadsheets