# Unable to generate URL to send to user for requesting access to a particular non-public google sheet

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been trying to solve this problem for the past couple of days but I am unable to succeed. 
I need to generate a url, which asks the user permission to read a particular Google Sheet of theirs, and if they agree, I will have access to read that sheet.

I have read and re-read the Google Sheet API [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), and the Google REST API for Node [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_install_the_client_library), but I am having trouble applying it to my particular case.

I was able to successfully use the REST API guide to read the meta details about all the files in the user's Google Drive, but what I actually need is to read (and only read, no other permission) just ONE google sheet. According to the Sheet API, the correct scope is `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds`, but that was all the information I could use from the API because the code is only written in Java/ .NET.

I have scoured the forums for answers,but most of them were very outdated and not applicable, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279272/how-to-access-private-google-spread-sheet-using-node-js) post which suggested using `node-google-spreadsheets`, but the documentation does not provide enough information as how to actually use it. I have attached my code below. Along with annotations as to where I am having problems with. I would appreciate ANY help as I have exhausted myself trying to make this to work. Thank you (:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
var GoogleSpreadsheets = require('google-spreadsheets');


var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']; //This scope works just fine when reading metadata, but to readspreedsheets, I think the correct one is: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';

fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }

  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});


/*************************************No Idea where to put this code:  

var oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
// Assuming you already obtained an OAuth2 token that has access to the correct scopes somehow...
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
    refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN
});

GoogleSpreadsheets({
    key: '<spreadsheet key>',
    auth: oauth2Client
}, function(err, spreadsheet) {
    spreadsheet.worksheets[0].cells({
        range: 'R1C1:R5C5'
    }, function(err, cells) {
        // Cells will contain a 2 dimensional array with all cell data in the
        // range requested.
    });
});



************************************************************/


function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}


function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}


function listFiles(auth) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  service.files.list({
    auth: auth,
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var files = response.files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Files:');
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        console.log('%s (%s)', file.name, file.id);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Edit1**: With the help of Sumnu2, I incorporated the `google-spreadsheets` (previously commented out). When I try to run the app, I get the following error: Not authorized to view the sheet. This makes sense because the sheet is private and I need to generate a link which allows me access to it. I have posted the code on haste bin [here](http://hastebin.com/azozocuqiq.coffee)

Comment: did you go as per the documentation ?

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for helping. Are you referring to node-google-spreadsheet? I am trying my best to follow the documentation, but I guess I am not doing a good job, hence I am here (:

Comment: I was talking about node-google-spreadsheet it worked on  mine can you do it once just for rechecking seems you skip some portion or is it possible to send the error ?

Comment: If I copy/paste the code from the documentation and add my creds, like [here](http://hastebin.com/awezewiluf.coffee), I get the following error in my console "ACCESS TOKEN(line 29) Not defined". If you look at the documentation, they dont really show how to go from getting the token after you are authenticated by the Google API, to generating a request URL, the documentation just says " Assuming you already obtained an OAuth2 token that has access to the correct scopes somehow.. ", which is the problem I am guessing.

Comment: ok so did you install all the packages which is mentioned on the top like fs , readline and so so ?

Comment: I actually forgot readline, but I installed it and I still get the same error (regarding the hastebin code I pasted), all other dependencies are installed.

Comment: try this http://hastebin.com/ilesujetol.coffee

Comment: I tried it, but my app crashed, [here](http://hastebin.com/uhureraqog.tex) is the log. I know the spreadsheet exists as I double checked, but I think it's not working because I was unable to authorize the request. As you can see from the log, it generates an authorization link, which you use to allow access to non-public files, but the app crashes before I have the time to copy-paste the generated code in the console.

Comment: I console.logged the error, and the reason the app crashes is because I do not have access to the spreadsheet

Comment: can you try with the public spread-sheets ? I tried with public its works fine.

Comment: It works fine with the public sheet but that's not what I want (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve it. The problem was I was not calling the correct Scopes, and passing in the wrong callback function to the `authorize` method. Here is the correct code :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
var GoogleSpreadsheets = require('google-spreadsheets');
var secrets = require('./client_secret.json');

var SCOPES = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/private/basic',
             ];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';

fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }

  authorize(JSON.parse(content), getSheet);
});



function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
   oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}


function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

function getSheet(auth) {
GoogleSpreadsheets({
    key: '<SpreadSheetKey>',
    auth: oauth2Client
}, function(err, spreadsheet) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('--------------err: ');
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('--------------reading sheet: ');  

        spreadsheet.worksheets[0].cells({

        }, function(err, cells) {
              console.log('================MADE IT HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');

              if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return;
              }

              for(var prop in cells) {
                  console.log('for loop');
                  var value = cells[prop];
                  console.log(prop, value);
              }

    });

    }
})
}
```